# MySQL edit last record with TRIGGER AFTER INSERT

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm quite new in MySQL and need some help concerning my challenge in Community Builder:

A user is on a CB registration form where a Text Field (named Invite_Code) is already automatically filled in. When the user submits the form, the record is updated in the table _comprofiler. Now I would like to change the field CB_Sponsor (also in _comprofiler) with a Sponsor name that can be found in table Invites.

Can this be done with a TRIGGER AFTER INSERT or BEFORE INSERT? And what Query
can do the job?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: yes, a trigger can cause changes in other tables in response to changes in the table the trigger's on. as for the query syntax: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: But I would like to EDIT the record in the TABLE that has just been inserted, NOT another table! Is that possible?

Comment: Meantime I've read that a trigger AFTER INSERT can not edit the last row. What kind of workaround is needed? An temp table to store data in? Or stored procedure?